# An absolute element is covered when making wrapper element relative

Tags: html, css

This is a question to a W3School example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

You can see the "Dropdown" button in header - it's not positioned as `relative`. If I make `.dropdown` element as `relative`, the `absolute` dropdown is not working anymore.

I created a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArtixZ/xyk3u2rv/). I only added one line at line 30.

Can some one explain - why the `absolute` dropdown is covered, when the wrapper element is positioned as `relative`?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I successfully made `.dropdown` a relative positioned element. Here is JsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ak80jqeh/

Answer (score 4):

Couple issues:

1. Your dropdown-content is ***absolute***, so you should specify where
   you are placing to the relative parent element  ***`position: relative`***.
   Use ***top***, ***left***, ***right*** and/or ***bottom***
   positioning to place the absolute element.
   positioning to place the absolute element.
2. Also, your overflow needs to be visible else you will not be able to see the dropdown content. By default not adding overflow will set it
   to visible so it can be removed.

I also removed the old float for nav items with **display: flex**, this will place elements within the flex element inline by default without the need to clear the floats.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {  
  /* !!! I'm making the wrapping element position as relative !!!*/
  position:relative;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  top: 46px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you applied 'overflow:hidden'.

As the parent's position changes to relative, the absolute can no longer ignore the overflow, so it becomes invisible.

[image]

Comment: But if you check off "overflow:hidden" in inspector, or just remove the code in JSFiddle,  it's still hidden.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `.dropdown` to `position: relative`, it means the child of this element is `.dropdown-content` (`position: absolute;`) can not show out of `.dropdown` box. So you can't see this.

Dropdown box size:

[image]

When `.dropdown` have `position: relative`:

[image]

When `.dropdown` have not `position: relative`:

[image]
Not related to `overflow: hidden` you can remove this line anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[***Relative***](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) - Even if you don’t set a z-index value, the relative element will now appear on top of any other statically positioned element. You can’t fight it by setting a higher z-index value on a statically positioned element.

**Wrapper:** `position: relative`.

`Dropdown` is going to the front.

[image: 2]

**Wrapper**: `position: static`

[image: 3]